# Is there a reason to wrap kwargs.get() with a try except statement in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch, keyword-argument

If I define a function, is it ever possible that an exception would be raised for kwargs.get? For example,

```
def func(**kwargs):
    try:
        a = kwargs.get("a")
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError("Would I ever see this error? \n ERROR: %s" % e )
```

Comment: what if the call does not send a dictionary as argument ?

Comment: it should be forced to a dictionary given the function signature....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `kwargs.get('somestring')` will not raise an exception; you are passed a standard Python `dict` type in that case.